# Excel dynamic drop downs based on previous selection

Tags: excel, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Good day,

I could only find examples where the tables are quite simple and the data minimal. I'm sitting with 36 makes, and up to 3 072 variants on the below data which I need sorted out.

The below col A through E is an extract of my data, with col G through I, the selections I need to make. To explain.

> Blockquote

Col G: Should be a drop down with the values from Col C (which is easy and is done already)

> Blockquote

Col H: If I now select Abarth in Col G, I only want the 500/695 or 124 displayed in a drop down, where I will choose 124

> Blockquote

Col I: Similar to Col H, now only Abarth 124 related items should be displayed in the drop down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I have written macros to resolve as follows:

```
Sub SelectModel()
'
' SelecModel Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Select

'   Save the active cell to use later
    Set myActiveCell = ActiveCell
    Set myActiveWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    Set myActiveWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=Sheets("2018MMCodes").Range("AU1")

    Sheets("2018MMCodes").Select
    If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    Columns("AV:AX").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Selections").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$3257").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:= _
        xlYes

    'Returns the user to the original sheet to enable just making a selection
    myActiveWorkbook.Activate
    myActiveWorksheet.Activate
    myActiveCell.Activate

End Sub
Sub SelectVariant()
'
' SelectVariant Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Select

'   Save the active cell to use later
    Set myActiveCell = ActiveCell
    Set myActiveWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    Set myActiveWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("2018MMCodes").Select
    Range("AU3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("AV:AX").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("AV1:AX3257").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("'2018MMCodes'!Criteria"), Unique:=False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Selections").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Returns the user to the original sheet to enable just making a selection
    myActiveWorkbook.Activate
    myActiveWorksheet.Activate
    myActiveCell.Activate

End Sub
```